# Loop Help For Storing Values From Text File

Tags: c#, string, loops, streamreader

I am reading in a text file and splitting it at delimited point.  Everything before the : is the left value, and everything after is the right. What is the best loop through the lines and store the string values into 2 lists, a left and a right? I don't need them to output, just store the values in the list.

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication8
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        id newId = new id();
        newId.Left = "";
        id newId2 = new id();
        newId2.Right = "";

    }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog of = new OpenFileDialog();
        of.ShowDialog();
        textBox1.Text = of.FileName;
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(of.FileName));

        string content = File.ReadAllText(of.FileName);
        string[] split = content.Split(';' , ':');
        foreach (string segment in split)
        {

            if 

        }

              }
```

Comment: Your code isn't complete and isn't even compiling.

Comment: Do you mean each line in the text file has a ':' ? And you want to split each line?

Comment: @elgonzo No, it's was just people arguing about who is right, Im not even asking for my code to be worked on Im asking for direction and nobody has lead me there.

Comment: @Smith.h.Neil yes, its delimited with : and ;

Comment: Ah, okay, i did not look at the answers. That's too bad indeed...

Comment: But you already have the string split into a string array. What hinders you to pick the strings from the array and stuff them into lists?

Comment: @user3617347 No I mean is each line delimited? Your description mentions looping through each line but your code appears that you want to split on the entire file instead of each line.

Comment: @elgonzo thats exactly what I want to do and cant complete correctly.  It seems so simple but it's giving me the biggest headache

Comment: @Smith.h.Neil yes each line is delimited like LNCD:JD84SD; then next line is similar to that

Comment: So you want LNCD added to the left list and JD84SD added to the right? I have an answer ready for you, just want to make sure I understand the question correctly.

Comment: @Smith.h.Neil yes, exactly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work. Not sure if you wanted the semicolon at the end so I just removed it.

```
var left = new List<string>();
var right = new List<string>();
using (var diag = new OpenFileDialog()) {
    if (diag.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) {
        using (var sr = new StreamReader(diag.FileName)) {
            string line;
            while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null) {
                var split = line.Replace(";", "").Split(':');
                if (split[0] != null && split[1] != null) {
                    left.Add(split[0]);
                    right.Add(split[1]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I noticed you mentioned this is a key/value thing so I would actually do:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
using (var diag = new OpenFileDialog()) {
    if (diag.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) {
        using (var sr = new StreamReader(diag.FileName)) {
            string line;
            while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null) {
                var split = line.Replace(";", "").Split(':');
                if (split[0] != null && split[1] != null)
                    dict.Add(split[0], split[1]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Could be cleaned up a bit but you see the point. You were reading the entire file and then splitting. How would you know which was on the left and right of each line? Maybe check even and odds? That's terrible though when you can just read a single line and then split that. Then just grab the first and second items in the array and you have your two items.

Comment: this works perfectly but the application remains open, can you recommend best place to run the eof or

Comment: What do you mean by the 'eof or'? If you just want to close after this executes and this is the only form, just add this.Close() at the end.

Answer (score 0):

For what you have provided, a `foreach` can do fine.

As for how to store them, that's entirely dependent on what you need to do with them. If the items on "left" are all unique, you can make a dictionary, where "left" is the key and "right" is the value. That would be easy to work with. Otherwise, if "left" is not unique, you can have a list of Tuples (`List<Tuple<string,string>>`) or KeyValuePairs (`List<KeyValuePair<string,string>>`).

Comment: That is exactly it to, the left would be a key and right would be the value of that

Comment: Ok. Then you can use the Dictionary.